# Use .Net Dll in Powerbuilder

Tags: c#, .net, powerbuilder

I have developed a .NET DLL in VisualStudio which should send e-mails via Outlook.

The developer of our ERP system wants to integrate this DLL and pass some parameters like sender and receiver, subject etc. to it.

He uses the following code:

```
OLEObject  obj_OES
long RetValue


obj_OES  = create OLEObject
RetValue = obj_OES.ConnectToNewObject("OutlookEMailSender.OutlookEMailSender")

Messagebox ( "ConnectToNewObject" , RetValue )

RetValue = obj_OES.object.SendMail("receiver","Test 1","account","sender","htmlbody","","C:\\data.pdf")

Messagebox ( "SendMail" , RetValue )
```

Our developer says that the code above only runs with registered DLLs.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What the developer means is that this code only works with COM libraries, which have to be registered. You need to expose types and interfaces using the proper COM Interoperability attributes, as [shown here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-net-com-assembly/)

Comment: BTW PowerBuilder [*does* work with .NET](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01261.1252/doc/html/hfr1233333899910.html), without requiring COM Interop. In v 12.5.2 there are two versions, PowerBuilder Classic and PowerBuilder .NET

Comment: @david heffernan: question is how our Developer can use my DLL in Powerbuilder

Comment: @panagiotis kanavos: Thank You, i will send this to our developer

Comment: What about some websearch. I'm sure that would work.

Comment: I wrote that i didnt found anything working on the Internet in days. But for some reason that was deleted by the Editor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose the .NET DLL as a COM library. Then PowerBuilder can consume it. You will need to register the DLL in the system the program will run on or use Registery-less COM.

Bruce Armstrong wrote an article explaining it here: http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/397016

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use OLE to interact with Outlook directly? The less moving parts the better. Here is a PowerBuilder code example:

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_outlook.html